# product of Mueller matrices

Tags: matrices

I am reading very old Fortran77 program. In the program, there is a subroutine for the product of two 4 x 4 Mueller Matrices.

The subroutine produces matrix "C" using matrix "A" and matrix "B".

The (1,1) element of the matrix "C" is

```
  C11 = C11                                                        
 1     + WK(J)*( A(1,1,I,J)*B(1,1,J,L)+A(1,2,I,J)*B(2,1,J,L)
 2              -A(1,3,I,J)*B(3,1,J,L)-A(1,4,I,J)*B(4,1,J,L))
```

where WK(J) is coefficients.

Similary the (1,2) element of the matrix "C" is

```
   C12 = C12                                                  
 1     + WK(J)*( A(1,1,I,J)*B(1,2,J,L)+A(1,2,I,J)*B(2,2,J,L) 
 2              -A(1,3,I,J)*B(3,2,J,L)-A(1,4,I,J)*B(4,2,J,L))
```

and so on.

For all the calculation for each element, only 4 elements from A and B are used.

What I do not understand well is why only 4 elements is used for the product for each element. I do not know whether this calculation is specific to Mueller matrix, or general for any matrix multiplication.

---

(added on May 24, 2014)

```
C11 = WK(J) * ( a11*b11 + a12*b21 - a13*b31 - a14*b41)
C12 = WK(J) * ( a11*b12 + a12*b22 - a13*b32 - a14*b42)
C13 = WK(J) * ( a11*b13 + a12*b23 + a13*b33 + a14*b43)
C14 = WK(J) * ( a11*b14 + a12*b24 + a13*b34 + a14*b44)

C21 = WK(J) * ( a21*b11 + a22*b21 - a23*b31 - a24*b41)
C22 = WK(J) * ( a21*b12 + a22*b22 - a23*b32 - a24*b42)
C23 = WK(J) * ( a21*b13 + a22*b23 + a23*b33 + a24*b43)
C24 = WK(J) * ( a21*b14 + a22*b24 + a23*b34 + a24*b44)

C31 = WK(J) * ( a31*b11 + a32*b21 + a33*b31 + a34*b41)
C32 = WK(J) * ( a31*b12 + a32*b22 + a33*b32 + a34*b42)
C33 = WK(J) * (-a31*b13 - a32*b23 + a33*b33 + a34*b43)
C34 = WK(J) * (-a31*b14 - a32*b24 + a33*b34 + a34*b44)

C41 = WK(J) * ( a41*b11 + a42*b21 + a43*b31 + a44*b41)
C42 = WK(J) * ( a41*b12 + a42*b22 + a43*b32 + a44*b42)
C43 = WK(J) * (-a41*b13 - a42*b23 + a43*b33 + a44*b43)
C44 = WK(J) * (-a41*b14 - a42*b24 + a43*b34 + a44*b44)
```

The multiplication has minus signs (-) for several parts. I do not have the clue on the rule of the minus signs.

Comment: it's correct except that each A has an extra I,J and every B has an extra J,L. Also, these do not seem to define the C values, they seem to be added to them, as an update. In any case, resistance is futile.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thank you for your comment. The J is used to sum up for a number of parameter (N2) for each of I. I didn't mention that. Resistance is futile. But I would like to resist to understand this.